# NFS automounter - files/dirs masked in mountpoints' parent directory

Tags: linux, nfs, share, automount, autofs

I have an NFS problem on a Redhat Ent Linux 5 host, in that I want to mount some NFS shares on `/opt/backup` and `/opt/stage`.

There are also some other dirs and files in `/opt` e.g. `/opt/myapp`, `/opt/otherapp`, `/opt/test`, etc which we want to access while the NFS shares are mounted.

Currently the NFS shares mounted on boot from `/etc/fstab` and all works well.

However we want to mount `/opt/backup` and `/opt/stage`  on demand via autofs/automounter instead of on boot from `/etc/fstab`.

I have this configured such that the NFS shares mount OK with autofs/automounter but
when  the automounter mount the NFS shares on the mount points I can not see the other files in `/opt`.

Is it possible to use the automounter to mount the NFS shares on `/opt/backup` and `/opt/stage` and still be able to access the other files in `/opt`, ie. `/opt/myapp`, `/opt/otherapp`, `/opt/test` etc?

If so how?

I have run a demo session which has been pasted it in below with some comments to try and help explain the problem.

Thanks.

Here's the demo:

`#` /opt has the two mount point dirs "backup" and "stage" as well as the dirs "lost+found" `#` "myapp" "otherapp" and the file "test"

```
[root@jttest6 etc]# ls /opt
backup  lost+found  myapp  otherapp  stage  test
```

`#` We list the NFS mountpoints - there are no files, the NFS shares are not
`#` mounted (Autofsd is not running at this point)

```
[root@jttest6 etc]# ls /opt/backup
[root@jttest6 etc]# ls /opt/stage
```

`#` This is what is in /etc/auto.master

```
[root@jttest6 etc]# grep -v ^# /etc/auto.master
/misc   /etc/auto.misc

/opt            /etc/auto.opt
/net    -hosts
+auto.master
```

`#` This is what is in /etc/auto.opt

```
[root@jttest6 etc]# cat /etc/auto.opt
backup          -rw,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192     nfs.icesa.catholic.edu.au:/opt/backup
stage           -
```

rw,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192     nfs.icesa.catholic.edu.au:/opt/stage

`#` we start autofs

```
[root@jttest6 etc]# service autofs start
Starting automount:  

                                  [  OK  ]
```

`#` we list the NFS mountpoints (I pipe into head because the listings are long - this
`#` is sufficient to show that something is now mounted there)

```
[root@jttest6 etc]# ls /opt/backup|head -2
ACL
brocade-backups
[root@jttest6 etc]# ls /opt/stage|head -2
ADF
ApplicationServer101202
```

`#` However we have now lost access to the dirs "lost+found" "myapp" "otherapp" and the file "test"

```
[root@jttest6 etc]# ls /opt
backup  stage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an indirect mount setup and it sounds like you want a direct mount point setup. Try:

```
/etc/auto.master
/- /etc/auto.opt

/etc/auto.opt
/opt/backup          -rw,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192     nfs.icesa.catholic.edu.au:/opt/backup
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0916/rfsrefer-72/index.html

Comment: Thanks Preston I'm not in a position to test this until next week, but I'll get back to you.

Comment: Glad to have helped!